# A theorem about totally transcendent theories

Tags: model-theory

I found this theorem in [T. Tao's notes](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/w-stable-theories1.pdf) on *totally transcendental* theories. A theory is t.t. if there is no binary tree of $L(M)$-formulas for any model $M$. I don't understand something about the proof. I'll state the theorem, and after I'll insert an image of the proof.

> **Theorem 1.4.** In a countable language $L$, consider a complete $L$-theory $T$. TFAE:
>
> 1. $T$ is t.t.;
> 2. $T$ is $\lambda$-stable, for any $\lambda\geq\aleph_0$;
> 3. $T$ is $\omega$-stable.

[image]

I don't understand why he can say that, "even if we exclude all *small formulas* from the set $U_{\phi}$, its cardinality is still greater than $\lambda$".

Comment: I just made some edits to your post to fix spelling and grammar, as well as the definition of t.t. - I hope that's ok with you. I also included a link to the document you're referring to.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really about cardinal arithmetic, not t.t. theories.

If $\psi(\overline{x})$ is small, then $|U_\psi|\leq \lambda$. Now there are only $\lambda$-many $L(A)$-formulas, so there are only $\lambda$-many *small* $L(A)$-formulas. Thus $$\bigcup_{\psi(\overline{x}) \text{ small}}U_\psi$$
is a union of at most $\lambda$-many sets, each of size at most $\lambda$, so $$\left|\bigcup_{\psi(\overline{x}) \text{ small}}U_\psi\right| \leq \lambda\times \lambda = \lambda.$$

But since $U_\phi$ is large, $|U_\phi|>\lambda$. It follows that $$\left|U_\phi\setminus \bigcup_{\psi(\overline{x}) \text{ small}}U_\psi\right| = |U_\phi| >\lambda.$$

Why? Well, if the cardinality of this set were $\leq \lambda$, then we could write $U_\phi$ as a disjoint union of two sets of size $\leq \lambda$, so we would have $|U_\phi| \leq 2\times \lambda = \lambda$, which is a contradiction.

In particular, the cardinality of this set is $\geq 2$, which is the conclusion that is used in the proof.

Comment: Now it's more ok, thank you and sorry for title mistake! I forgot one other thing: in the third implication, why we can say that every branch of binary tree forms a type over $A$?

Comment: @Silvie Every branch gives a set of formulas (a partial type). What we need to check is that this set of formulas is consistent, and hence can be completed to a complete type. Consistency follows from the compactness theorem: Every finite subset of a branch is equivalent to one of the formulas in that finite subset, which is consistent by definition of the tree, so by compactness the entire branch is consistent

Comment: Is there a theorem which explains that "if a set of formulas is consistent,  then it can be completed to a complete type"? Anyway, everything very clear, thanks again!

Comment: @Silvie If a set of formulas is consistent, then there is some tuple from a model which satisfies them. Take the complete type of that tuple.